# How to describe sand falling onto a hard surface

Tags: word-choice, verbs

How would you describe sand or some other crystal-like powder like salt falling onto a hard surface? What sound does it make? What verb would you use? Scattering?

Comment: Are you looking for onomatopoeia?  I don't know of any established spelling for imitating the sound in English...  I thought I might say *fffft* for very fine sand, but I don't imagine many English speakers would understand that without enough context to let them know what I was trying to imitate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scatter](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/scatter) means that the sand or salt fell randomly unto the hard surface. Like the wind scattered sand all over the surfboard. Is that would you mean? If not, you need to be more specific! If I held the sand in my hand in one position over the surface and let the sand fall upon it, this would not be scattering. If the the sand/salt falls "fall quickly and very heavily" you can use [pelt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/pelt). What it sounds like might depend on which situation is closer to what you have in mind. *Pelt*, to me, is onomatopoeic, that is, the word sounds like what it describes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably **hiss**.

> A light wind carried a film of sand hissing up against our legs,

-Gobi, Tracking the Desert, by John Man

> Nick listened. All his being was consumed with listening. He could
>   hear the sand hissing along the road. The truck creaked.

- Thieves' Market, by Albert Bezzerides